# Could not find or load main class sqlline.SqlLine Error while starting Apache Drill

Tags: java, apache-drill

I am new to Apache Drill. I have java version 1.7.0_79. My Hadoop-1.2.1 installation is pseudo-distributed single node setup on Ubuntu-14.04. I have downloaded Drill-1.1.0. from Official website. I untarred the tar ball and set its path in .bashrc file. I started Drill using `bin/drillbit.sh start`, it said `starting drillbit, logging to /usr/lib/drill/log/drillbit.out`. But when I check its status using `bin/drillbit.sh status` , it says `/usr/lib/drill/drillbit.pid file is present but drillbit not running.` Did I miss any step in configuring Drill?

When I run `bin/sqlline -u jdbc:drill:zk=local` command to start drill shell, it shows the following error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
Error: Could not find or load main class sqlline.SqlLine
```

Why is drillbit not running? How can I rectify this error and start using Drill shell?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Drill on a computer that is not in a cluster, you do not start the Drillbit [per the docs](http://drill.apache.org/docs/starting-drill-in-distributed-mode/#using-the-drillbit.sh-command). The Drillbit is not supposed to run outside of a cluster. Stop the Drillbit (kill the Java process if necessary). If your OS is Linux or Mac, use one of the methods for [starting Drill on Linux or Mac](http://drill.apache.org/docs/starting-drill-on-linux-and-mac-os-x/): drill-embedded is recommended. Otherwise, see the [Windows start method](http://drill.apache.org/docs/starting-drill-on-windows/).

Comment: My Hadoop installation is pseudo-distributed single node setup and my OS is linux. I have used 'bin/drill-embedded' but the same error follows.

Comment: Please check the Drillbit status to make sure it's running: drillbit.sh status. What does the drillbit.out log say? Try the drill-localhost command to start it or in the sqlline command instead of zk=local, provide an ip address or hostname.

Comment: This is my drillbit.out log    `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000006c0000000, 4294967296, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 4294967296 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /usr/lib/drill/hs_err_pid10442.log
`

Comment: Can you share your drill-env.sh, drill-override.conf con files & drillbit.out log file on gist or someplace online?